# Kernel does not use RTC

Tags: archlinux, systemd, rtc

I have a PiFace RTC clock that I have setup on archlinux ARM on a rpi2.

I have edited `/boot/config.txt` to add

```
dtparam=i2c=on
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,mcp7941x=0x6f
```

I have added **i2c-dev** and **i2c:mcp7941x** modules to `/etc/modules-load.d/raspberrypi.conf`

But the kernel does not seem to use it to update the system clock. I can see the rtc driver is loaded:

```
 kernel: rtc-ds1307 1-006f: registered as rtc0
```

and there is a `/dev/rtc0` device. But the kernel does not update system clock with it.

It is only **systemd-timesyncd** that restores time from saved timestamp. And then later on sync time with SNTP if I have a network available.

The idea of having a RTC is to have correct time if there is no network.

But this is not used at all.

How do I tell the kernel to use the RTC to update system clock at boot ? or only if there is no internet connection ?

Comment: Enable RTC in Device Tree

Comment: Could you be more specific ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, an ugly hack is to make a `hwclock.service` like this

```
[Unit]
Description=Synchronize system clock from RTC

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/hwclock --hctosys
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=time-sync.target
```

And enable it with

```
sudo systemctl enable hwclock.service
```

It will step on *systemd-timesyncd*'s toes when network is available but should do no harm.

In the hope of a better solution ?

**Another way to do it**, is to use an *udev* rule that trigger *hwclock*.

in `/etc/udev/rules.d/i2c-rtc.rules`

```
KERNEL=="rtc0", SUBSYSTEM=="rtc", SUBSYSTEMS=="i2c", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="hwclock.service"
```

in `/etc/systemd/system/hwclock.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Synchronize system clock from RTC

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/hwclock --hctosys --utc
Type=oneshot
```